# SQL Select Count(*)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables with this structure:

Table_1:

```
Column_A(P_Key)    Column_B
  Val1             Location1
  Val2             Location1
  Val3             Location2
  Val4             Location3
  Val4             Location4
  Val4             Location5
```

Table_2:

```
   Column_A(P_Key)    Column_B   Column_C
   Location1          Person_1    Person_2
   Location2          Person_1    Person_3
   Location3          Person_3    Person_4
   Location4          Person_1    Person_5
   Location5          Person_2    Person_3
```

I need a query to Count the number of items that each person is responsible for in each location:

For Example the query should return:

```
Person     Total
Person_1     4
Person_2     3
Person_3     3
Person_4     1
Person_5     1
```

This is for SQL Server 2008 R2

Thank you!

Comment: So, it's a straight shot really :

`SELECT COUNT(column_names_desired)` Right? give it a little shot

Comment: You should check out the `GROUP BY` keyword

Comment: Yep, and you'll need a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be inclined to unpivot the second table and then re-aggregate:

```
select person, count(*)
from ((select column_b as person
       from table2 t2 join
            table1 t1
            on t2.column_a = t1.column_b
      ) union all
      (select column_c as person
       from table2 t2 join
            table1 t1
            on t2.column_a = t1.column_b
      )
     ) p
group by person
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

If i correctly unterstand your needs this query should meet your expectations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.column_a AS person,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 t1 WHERE t1.column_b = t.column_a) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t2.column_c = t.column_a) AS Total
FROM
    table_2 t
```